# Giving JMenuItem's name to it's ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, menu, actionlistener

How can I give my `JMenuItem`s names that the `ActionListener` attached to them will look at?

I've got a menu system that's handled by a single `ActionListener`, and some items in those menus duplicate names.  This isn't a problem on the user end, because it's obvious what does what; in fact, it would be more confusing if they had different names.  However, at my end, I want to label each item uniquely.

The section that creates my items looks like this:

```
String label = getLabel(forThisItem);
JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(label);
item.setName(parentMenu.getName() + "_" + label);
item.addActionListener(actionListener);
parentmenu.add(item);
```

Interrogating the item afterwards (and outside the scope of this method) with getName() gives the name I gave it, as it should, but the output of

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    String actionPerformed = ae.getActionCommand();
    System.out.println("actionPerformed: " + actionPerformed);
}
```

is the the, possibly duplicated, name that the user sees, specified by `label`, not the unique name that I gave it.

How can I give the right information to the ActionListener?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why aren't you calling `setActionCommand` on the menuitem.  Instead of using `setName`, if you call `setActionCommand`, you should get what you expect when you call `getActionCommand`

Also, its *label*, not *lable*.

Answer (score 5):

another way as implementing inner [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) (with `setActionCommand(String actionCommand)`) for whole [JMenu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) is wrote [java.swing.Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for each of `JMenuItem` or implements [EventHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/EventHandler.html) (seems like as valid for all `Listeners` that I tried)

example about JButtons and with implemented `ActionListener` and `EventHandler` (both [Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) firing events)

EDIT: `EventHandler` os too hacky, because in Swing aren't another direct method how to call code_block by String value

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.EventHandler;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/** based on  @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702697 */
public class GridButtonPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final int N = 2;
    private final List<GridButton> list = new ArrayList<GridButton>();

    public GridButtonPanel() {
        super(new GridLayout(N, N));
        for (int i = 0; i < N * N; i++) {
            int row = i / N;
            int col = i % N;
            GridButton gb = new GridButton(row, col);
            gb.addActionListener((ActionListener) EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class, this,
                    "actionName" + row + "A" + col));
            list.add(gb);
            this.add(gb);
        }
    }

    public void actionName0A0() {
        System.out.println(" Grid at Row 0, Column 0 ");
    }

    public void actionName0A1() {
        System.out.println(" Grid at Row 0, Column 1 ");
    }

    public void actionName1A0() {
        System.out.println(" Grid at Row 1, Column 0 ");
    }

    public void actionName1A1() {
        System.out.println(" Grid at Row 1, Column 1 ");
    }

    private GridButton getGridButton(int r, int c) {
        int index = r * N + c;
        return list.get(index);
    }

    private class GridButton extends JButton {

        private int row;
        private int col;

        public GridButton(int row, int col) {
            super("Row - " + row + ",  Col - " + col);
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
            this.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int r = GridButton.this.row;
                    int c = GridButton.this.col;
                    GridButton gb = GridButtonPanel.this.getGridButton(r, c);
                    System.out.println("r" + r + ",c" + c
                            + " " + (GridButton.this == gb)
                            + " " + (GridButton.this.equals(gb)));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("GridButton");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GridButtonPanel().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```