# Dynamical adding MenuItem with references

Tags: java, swing, dynamic

I have x ports in my computer. I woud like to add to menu any device is plug into and recive user input for listener. I wrote:

```
private void portSelectItem(){

    JMenu port=new JMenu("Port");

    String[] portTab= SerialIO.listPorts();

    for(String s : portTab){                    

        port.add(new JCheckBoxMenuItem(s));

    }

}
```

With way I generate dynamical x references and add listener in this ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Swing menus [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html). Here is an example:

```
ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
for(String s : portTab){                    
    JCheckBoxMenuItem checkBoxMenuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem();  
    checkBoxMenuItem.setText(s);
    buttonGroup.add(checkBoxMenuItem);
    checkBoxMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //TODO 
        }
    });         
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) `setActionCommand(String portTab)`

2) you can add to `JCheckBoxMenuItem`

- [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- [ChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html)
- [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html)
- [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)
- most complex way is add [EventHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/EventHandler.html), which [fired event and could be compare in String value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9007348/714968)

3) each of [Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) returns [Object fired select/deselect event](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/EventfiringsequenceActionListenerItemListenerandChangeListener.htm), and this `Object` returns `getActionCommand(String portTab)` if is defined