# Multiple buttons and multiple listeners doing various operations Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, event-listener

How can I have multiple buttons and multiple listeners doing various operations in java swing. Here is an example of what I have, I can redirect to the AddStudent class but the button to redirect to the AddAdult class wont redirect to the AddAdult class.

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
  // handle button event
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent Student ) {
    if ( Student.getSource() == button1 ){
      try {
        AddStudent newmember = new AddStudent();
        newmember.setVisible( true );
      } catch ( Exception e1 ) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}


public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent Adult ) {
  if ( Adult.getSource() == button2 ){
    try {
      AddAdult newmember = new AddAdult();
      newmember.setVisible( true );
    } catch ( Exception e1 ) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "wont work"? Also, the posted code won't compile because the second method is not in a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach an `ActionListener` to each `JButton`, as explained in the [Swing tutorial for buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

So you will end up with something like

```
JButton firstButton = ...;
firstButton.addActionListener( myFirstButtonActionListener );

JButton secondButton = ...;
secondButton.addActionListener( mySecondActionListener );

//add them to a UI
contentPane.add( firstButton );
contentPane.add( secondButton );
```

For more specific questions about your program and your button you will need to provide us with more code then is currently available in your question (in other words, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/))

Comment: Thanks, that was the kind of example I was looking for. @Robin

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have multiple handlers, you can define multiple classes each implementing ActionListener interface with appropriate logic implemented and attach it to appropriate buttons.
If you want to use single handler for all buttons, you can use getActionCommand() (more clear than using getSource()) method of ActionEvent to check for the button text and implement your handling logic accordingly using if else.

Answer (score 1):

you have three another ways

1) use [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

```
       myPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("some narrative") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //some stuff
            }
        }));
```

2) use inner ActionListener

code

```
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        //some stuff
    }
});
```

3) use [EventHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9007348/714968)