# Java: input a matrix using GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, input, matrix, grid-layout

I am trying to write a function that can input a matrix of any size using a GridLayout, but I'm stuck since I can't find an appropriate way of extracting the JTextField values to fill the 'mat' var (see FIXME below).

```
    /**
     * @mat: matrix declared in main (e.g: mat[][] = new int[3][3];)
     * @rows: number of matrix rows (e.g: int rows = 3;)
     * @columns: number of matrix columns (e.g: int columns = 3;)
     */
    public static int[][] inputMatrix(int[][] mat, int rows, int columns)
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();     
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows,columns));

        for (int a=0; a<(rows*columns); a++)
        {
            panel.add(new JTextField(a));
        }

        if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Enter the matrix", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION)
                                        == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
        {
            for(int a=0; a<(rows*columns); a++){
                for(int b=0; b<rows; b++){
                    for(int c=0; c<columns; c++){
                        /* FIXME: find how to extract JTextField values. */
                        mat[b][c] = JTextField.a.getText();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return mat;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

- use [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) instead of bunch of `JTextField` layed by `GridLayout`

or

- add there `putClientProperty` and to add [identifier `Row` a `Column` from `GridLayout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9007348/714968)
- put `JTextField` to the `HashMap`
- I would be preferring `putClientProperty` (you can to multiplay number or additional infos.., number of separate `putClientProperty` isn't somehow reduced)
- depends of (not clear) desing, you can to add `ActionListener` to `JTextField` (accelerator is `ENTER key`) or `DocumentListener`

virtual example, code example for `JButton` and `ActionListener`, `putClientProperty` is accesible from all methods or `Listeners` added to `JTextField`

in the loop

```
buttons[i][j].putClientProperty("column", i);
buttons[i][j].putClientProperty("row", j);
buttons[i][j].addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
```

and get from ActionListener (for example)

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
        System.out.println("clicked column " + btn.getClientProperty("column")
                + ", row " + btn.getClientProperty("row"));
}
```

Comment: Hi, the `JTable` way looks good, could you detail it a bit more ?
I will look into the other one too. ty

Comment: @user1847810 Start from [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). All Swing components have a corresponding tutorial at Oracle/Sun which are almost all a very good start point.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a 3-row x 3-column grid.  Since GridLayout adds by rows, then the 1st item of the second row would be the 4th item that you added to the grid.  You could retrieve this item by calling panel.getComponent(3) (zero index so 4th item is at index 3).

So - you could just use getComponent, doing a little math to figure out the right index based on the number of columns and the i,j coordinates in the matrix.

Comment: Hi, I tried `mat[b][c] = Integer.parseInt(panel.getComponent(a));` but it says "Cannot convert from component to int."
Am I missing something here ? ty

Comment: @user1847810 the component itself is not an `int` (but probably a `JTextField`). You could try this instead: `mat[b][c] = Integer.parseInt(((JTextField)panel.getComponent(a)).getText());`. But my advice would be to follow mKorbel solution and use a `JTable` which is actually meant for your purposes.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet That works for me, but yeah looks very dirty.