# Drawing and deleting jlabels from a jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I am making a chess game gui by setting up a grid of jpanels with jlabels on top (the piece images). I set up the board with each square (jpanel) having an empty jlabel w/ visibility set to false. I then go through each of the jpanels and set the jlabel picture to an image corresponding to one of my pieces. I know whether or not to draw a piece because I have a variable _board[8][8] that tells me if that spot is occupied and by whom. This is how I create the original board:

EDIT:

I actually changed this up quite a bit, that way I don't have to reload images each time:

```
public ChessGameGUI(Square[][] board) throws IOException 
    {
        Dimension size = new Dimension(500, 400);
        Dimension boardSize = new Dimension(400, 400);

        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(size);

        theBoard = new JPanel();
        layeredPane.add(theBoard, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        layeredPane.addMouseListener(this);

        GridLayout chessBoardLayout = new GridLayout(8,8);
        theBoard.setLayout(chessBoardLayout);
        theBoard.setPreferredSize(boardSize);
        theBoard.setBounds(0, 0, boardSize.width, boardSize.height);

        boolean drawWhite = true;

        // setup initial squares
        for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
            {
                BorderLayout squareBorder = new BorderLayout();
                JPanel aChessSquare = new JPanel(squareBorder);

                if(drawWhite) aChessSquare.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                else aChessSquare.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

                // load initial images
                if(board[x][y]._isOccupied)
                {
                    BufferedImage logo = null;

                    try{
                        // load the image
                        String path = findPieceImagePath(board, x, y);
                        logo = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
                        ImageIcon pieceImage = new ImageIcon(logo);

                        JLabel pieceJLabel = new JLabel();
                        pieceJLabel.setIcon(pieceImage); // new
                        pieceJLabel.setVisible(true); // new

                        aChessSquare.add(pieceJLabel);
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e)
                    { 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    } // end try catch
                }// end if
                else
                {
                    JLabel pieceJLabel = new JLabel();
                    pieceJLabel.setVisible(false);
                    aChessSquare.add(pieceJLabel);
                }

                theBoard.add(aChessSquare);

                // alternate background colors
                if(x == 7);
                else drawWhite = !drawWhite;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("the number of components = " + theBoard.getComponentCount());

    }
```

This loads the initial board just fine, however I can't seem to get a specific component. When I click on one of the pieces, that square should light up. The only square that ever gets the green outline is the one in the top left (0, 0).

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        System.out.println("mouse press x = " + e.getX() + " y = " + e.getY());

        // find which piece on the board is being clicked
        int gameX, gameY;
        gameX = e.getX() / 50;
        gameY = e.getY() / 50;

        System.out.println("gameX = " + gameX + " gameY = " + gameY);

        // out of bounds
        if(gameX < 0 || gameY < 0) return;

        // true if selected a piece on this team
        if(myGame._board[gameX][gameY]._isOccupied && !_pieceSelected && myGame._board[gameX][gameY]._team == myGame._turn) 
        {
            System.out.println("selected new piece");
            JPanel curSquare = (JPanel)theBoard.getComponentAt(gameX, gameY);
            curSquare.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green));
            _pieceSelected = !_pieceSelected;



            return;
        }
```

I guess I am having problems with this line: JPanel curSquare = (JPanel)theBoard.getComponentAt(gameX, gameY);

however, the gameX and gameY values are being set properly.

Thanks

Comment: Aagh! Hurts... my... eyes... You are loading the image every time you render the board.

Comment: Simply add the labels to a 2D array, which would make it easier to access the label

Comment: Image loading will be slow every time. A quick optimisation would be to use a Map<String, ImageIcon> (string would be the "path") to act as a cache and avoid loading things you've already loaded before. There are other ways (a ChessPiece enum or class that stores its ImageIcon along with it, etc.) but that's a whole different kettle of fish.

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621870/how-to-work-with-a-specific-element-in-gridlayout/14626413#14626413) example.

Comment: Could someone please take a look at the changes?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a line to add the label to each panel. During "// setup initial squares":

```
curLabel.setVisible(false);
```

Should be:

```
curLabel.setVisible(false);
aChessSquare.add(curLabel);
```