# creating new jpanels using loop

Tags: java, swing, loops, object, jpanel

i creating new jpanels using loop. but how i using different object name. 
here is my code:

```
for(int i=0; i<panelnumbers.length(); i++){
    MainConfig.page21.addNewPanel(MainConfig.page21.pos1, "INFORMACIÓN No. " + (i + 2));
}

public static void addNewPanel(int y, String title) {
    Add a = new Add(title);
    jLayeredPane3.add(a);
    a.setBounds(0, y, 1333, 450);
    jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1333, (pos + 480)));
    jLayeredPane3.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1333, (pos + 480)));
    jLayeredPane3.validate();
    jScrollPane1.getViewport().setViewPosition(new Point(0, (pos + 480)));
}
```

Comment: `but how i using different object name` - what do you actually want to do?

Comment: i want to give different name each panel object.

Comment: You mean through the [setName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29) method?

Comment: You should definitely use a layout manager like GridBagLayout (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Answer (score 1):

> i creating new jpanels using loop. but how i using different object
>   name.

- use [JPanel.get/putClientProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29),

  1. you can to multiply this method
  2. every events this/these value, e.g. [from Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html)
  3. [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13531549/714968)

Answer (score 1):

You are using absolute coordinates, a layout manager gives a better GUI across platforms, later Windows versions, accessibility etcetera.

```
MainConfig.page21.setLayout(new BoxLayout(MainConfig.page21, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Also normally one would not need the JPanel, an event listener would know how to retrieve the panel.

Nevertheless you could maintain an array of JPanels:

```
List<JPanel> panels = new ArrayList<>();
```

In addPanel create a local variable, and add that

```
public void addNewPanel(int y, String title) { // Not static
    JPanel panel = new JPane();
    ...
    panels.add(panel);
}
```

Comment: thank you. it's good idea. but i don't know how many panels adding at runtime. it's unlimited jpanel.

Comment: Okay I'll change the code. Thought fixed because of i, and for loop.

Comment: Mind, `addNewPanel` is no longer static, as using `panels`.

Comment: i fixed my problem. Thank's all. i like stackoverflow's experts