# Is it possible to create new buttons to a frame via action listener?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

This is my code and i would like to know if I can add new buttons to my grid layout every time I click one of the already existing buttons to the instance frame.

```
public class Board {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JButton[] button = new JButton[40];
            int i = 0;
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(20, 20, 15, 15));
            while (i < 40) {
                button[i] = new JButton("button" + i);
                button[i].addActionListener(new Action());
                frame.add(button[i]); 
                i++;
            }
            frame.setSize(700, 700);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        static class Action implements ActionListener{
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988317/dynamically-add-components-to-a-jdialog/6988341#6988341).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is rather simple.

What you need to do is think about the problem.  Firstly, you have a bunch of `static` references which really aren't required and provide you with little benefit.

Now, having said that.  You `Action` needs some way to know where to add the button.  In order to do this, the `Action` needs a reference to the container you want to add the buttons to...

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Board {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Board();
    }

    public Board() {
        JButton[] button = new JButton[40];
        int i = 0;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(20, 20, 15, 15));
        Action action = new Action(frame);
        while (i < 40) {
            button[i] = createButton(i);
            button[i].addActionListener(action);
            frame.add(button[i]);
            i++;
        }
        action.setCount(i);
        frame.setSize(700, 700);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JButton createButton(int index) {

        return new JButton("button" + index);

    }

    public class Action implements ActionListener {

        private JFrame frame;
        private int count;

        public Action(JFrame frame) {
            this.frame = frame;
        }

        public void setCount(int count) {
            this.count = count;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton btn = createButton(count);
            btn.addActionListener(this);
            frame.add(btn);
            frame.revalidate();
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @syb0rg Your answer was almost valid, it just missed the point of how to get the newly created button onto the OP's UI

Comment: Thank you both for your answers.They helped me a lot.

Comment: I'd be to use reverse idea, [used by (@trashgod) or (@HFOE)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9007348/714968)