# Trying to add ActionListener to JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I cannot figure out how to add `Actionlisteners` to the `JButton`s, any help would be much appreciated.

```
public class Translator extends JPanel implements MouseListener, ActionListener {       

    private JButton french = new JButton();
    private JButton german = new JButton();
    private JButton irish = new JButton();

    public Translator(){
        french = new JButton("French");
        german = new JButton("German");
        irish = new JButton("Irish");           
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));         
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
        buttonPanel.add(french);
        buttonPanel.add(german);
        buttonPanel.add(irish);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: `buttonName.addActionListener(this);`

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of ways to add an `ActionListener`, to a given `JComponent` (that supports it's use). I have added some comments in the code snippets, to help explain them a bit better, and some links in the comments for future reference.

1.) **If the class implements the `ActionListener` interface, i.e. the class itself contains the `actionPerformed(...)` method**, then one can do it, in this manner:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Skeleton implements ActionListener {   

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton button;

    private void displayGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Skeleton");
        /*
         * EXIT_ON_CLOSE is same as putting System.exit(0),
         * which in some sense, doesnot allows one's
         * application to terminate graciously.
         */ 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton("This is a button.");
        /*
         * This is one way of attaching an ActionListener
         * to the JButton, but the main disadvantage of
         * this approach is, it breaks encapsulation,
         * as you can see the public method, actionPerformed(),
         * is lying free to be accessed by any code outside
         * the scope of the class
         */
        button.addActionListener(this);

        contentPane.add(button);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);                                
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Skeleton().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "BINGO!",
            "Information: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }    
}
```

2.) **If one doesn't wants to create unnecessary `class` files. Then this approach, which uses, `EventHandler` can be used:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.EventHandler;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example1 { 

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton button;

    private void displayGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Skeleton");
        /*
         * EXIT_ON_CLOSE is same as putting System.exit(0),
         * which in some sense, doesnot allows one's
         * application to terminate graciously.
         */ 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton("This is a button.");
        /*
         * This is another way of attaching 
         * an ActionListener to the JButton,
         * the main advantage of this approach
         * is, that one does not have to create
         * a new class to handle events
         * More info regarding the use of this 
         * approach, can be found on this link : 
         * http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html
         */
        button.addActionListener((ActionListener)
                EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class
                        , Example1.this, "buttonAction", ""));

        contentPane.add(button);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);                                
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example1().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }

    public void buttonAction(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "BINGO!",
            "Information: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }    
}
```

3.) **If one is more concern about the concept of `Encapsulation`, then this approach is beneficial:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example2 { 

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton button;

    private ActionListener buttonActions = 
                            new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "BINGO!",
                "Information: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    };

    private void displayGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Skeleton");
        /*
         * EXIT_ON_CLOSE is same as putting System.exit(0),
         * which in some sense, doesnot allows one's
         * application to terminate graciously.
         */ 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton("This is a button.");
        /*
         * This is another way of attaching 
         * an ActionListener to the JButton,
         * the main advantage of this approach
         * is, it adheres to encapsulation.
         */
        button.addActionListener(buttonActions);

        contentPane.add(button);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);                                
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example2().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }    
}
```

4.) **If one is more inclined towards creation of Anonymous Classes, then this approach can be used:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example3 { 

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton button;

    private void displayGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Skeleton");
        /*
         * EXIT_ON_CLOSE is same as putting System.exit(0),
         * which in some sense, doesnot allows one's
         * application to terminate graciously.
         */ 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton("This is a button.");
        /* 
         * This is the fourth way of attaching  
         * an ActionListener to the JButton, 
         * the main advantage of this approach 
         * is, it adheres to encapsulation, the 
         * public method remains hidden
         * inside the Anonymous Class
         * More info can be found on this link : 
         * http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html
         * The main disadvantage of this approach is
         * that it doesnot gives you the privilege
         * of separation of concerns, which can
         * be done using the fifth approach,
         * which is MVC - Pattern (Model-View-Controller)
         * and moreover, it creates a hell lot of classes, in 
         * your project, which can lead to extra overhead
         */
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "BINGO!",
                    "Information: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

        contentPane.add(button);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);                                
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example3().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }    
}
```

**EDIT:**

5.) **This approach, includes using `Action` instead of `ActionListener`. This is to be used for sharing same functionality among various `JComponent`s, which leads to code reusability**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example4 { 

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JMenuItem showMenuItem;
    private JButton button;

    private Action myActions;

    /*
     * This approach is basically used, when
     * one wants to share the same functionality
     * of different JComponents among each other,
     * without writing redundant codes for each
     * one of those components. Here JMenuItem
     * and JButton are both using the same 
     * functionality, to perform the same task.
     * More info can be found on this link:
     * http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html
     */
    private class MyActions extends AbstractAction {
        public MyActions(String title, String desc) {
            super(title);
            putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, desc);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "BINGO!",
                    "Information: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    private void displayGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Skeleton");
        /*
         * EXIT_ON_CLOSE is same as putting System.exit(0),
         * which in some sense, doesnot allows one's
         * application to terminate graciously.
         */ 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton("This is a button.");

        myActions = new MyActions("Show", "A small description");
        button.setAction(myActions);

        contentPane.add(button);

        frame.setJMenuBar(getJMenuBar());
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);                                
    }

    private JMenuBar getJMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        showMenuItem = new JMenuItem(myActions);
        fileMenu.add(showMenuItem);

        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        return menuBar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example4().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }    
}
```

Comment: +1 Since you've gone this far, maybe you want to add `Actions` to the mix ;-)

Comment: @splungebob [I'm suprised that this old war 
(as you are) on Java Forums don't know something about](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9007348/714968)

Answer (score 1):

```
french.addActionListener(an_instance_of_the_class_where_actionPerformed_is);
```

which, as I can see after the edit, would be `this`

Also, see [this Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ButtonDemoProject/src/components/ButtonDemo.java) and some tutorial text in this corner of the web

I think that the reference to the tutorial and the many examples is highly relevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
button.addActionListener(<your_ActionListener_here>);
```

In your case, it'll be:

```
french.addActionListener(this);
```

If you want to use the same ActionListener for all the three buttons, you can use the getSource() function of ActionEvent e to detect which button was actually pressed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java8, you can try this.

```
JButton french = new JButton("French");
french.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        System.out.println("Button french clicked!");
    }
});
french.addActionListener(button -> System.out.println("Button Click listener..."));
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Listener Test");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(french, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setSize(250, 250);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: It better not to name the `ActionEvent` variable as `button`.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the answer is place `this` into your `addActionListener` method.

The `addActionListener` method takes as an argument an object that *implements* `ActionListener` interface, this interface force you to implements/place-in-your-code the`actionPerformed` method which is the one that is called, when an action is triggered to the component that is assigned.

So, placing `this` in your method, it will search inside the object you passed, in our case, the `Translator` object for an `actionPerformed` method and call it.

```
this.french.addActionListener(this);
```

Of course there is a lot of code missing in order to work.

I really liked @Sandeep answer take use of lambda expression.
You can see a full example below.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Translator extends JPanel implements ActionListener {       

    private JButton french = new JButton();
    private JButton german = new JButton();
    private JButton irish = new JButton();

    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public Translator(){
        french = new JButton("French");
        german = new JButton("German");
        irish = new JButton("Irish");           
//        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));         
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
        this.add(french);
        this.add(german);
        this.add(irish);

        ActionListener ac = (ActionEvent ae) -> { System.out.println(((JButton) ae.getSource()).getText()); };
        this.french.addActionListener(ac);
        this.german.addActionListener(ac);
        this.irish.addActionListener(ac);
        this.irish.addActionListener(Translator.this);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(((JButton) e.getSource()).getText());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame("StackOverflow");
        jframe.add(new Translator());
        jframe.pack();
        jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JButton button = new JButton("Button");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //To-Do
        //Button clicked
        });
```

Hope this helps, it's relatively simple! You just need to add an ActionListener to your desired JButton

To give you a broader idea of how to implement it in a case-scenario where I would like to run a new GUI frame after pressing a button:

```
startNewFrame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Starting new frame");
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    NewFrame newFrame = new NewFrame();
                    newFrame.setVisible(true);
                    dispose();//Disposes of current frame
                }
            });
        }
    });
```