# swing Jbutton listener not working

Tags: java, swing, listener, jbutton

While trying to read data from `JTextField` it says:

```
cannot refer to non final variable declared in inner class in another method
```

---

**CODE:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Soloswing {

    Soloswing() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("soloworld");
        jf.setLayout(new FlowLayout(5, 25, 10));
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("VALUE1");
        JTextField t1 = new JTextField(20);
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("VALUE2");
        JTextField t2 = new JTextField(20);
        JLabel l3 = new JLabel("RESULT");
        JTextField t3 = new JTextField(20);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("+");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("-");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("*");
        JButton b4 = new JButton("/");
        JButton b5 = new JButton("%");
        JButton bequals = new JButton("=");
        JButton bclear = new JButton("CE");
        //int i = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
        //int j = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());

        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setSize(300, 500);
        jf.add(l1);
        jf.add(t1);
        jf.add(l2);
        jf.add(t2);
        jf.add(l3);
        jf.add(t3);
        jf.add(b1);
        jf.add(b2);
        jf.add(b3);
        jf.add(b4);
        jf.add(b5);
        jf.add(bequals);
        jf.add(bclear);

        jf.setVisible(true);
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int j = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
                int k = i + j;
                t3.setText(k);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Soloswing();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So, what I expect is, when `JButton` is clicked it should read inputs from two `JTextField`s and add them together and show the result in the third  textField

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int j = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
        int k = i + j;
        t3.setText(k);
    }
});
```

But, it shows the error:

```
canot refer to non final variable declared in inner class in another  method
```

Comment: Solution: don't use inner variables but rather change some key inner variables into non-static class fields, in particular your JTextFields. Note, if you had searched on your error message, you likely would have found a gazillion similar questions on this site.

Comment: One more similar [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13208755/1057230), hope it also helps :-)

Comment: can you show link to solutions to problems similar like this

Comment: @user3886433: Please see, if you can get one idea from, [Trying to add ActionListeners to JButton](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25627775/1057230).

Comment: >after changing the test field values to final the program works fine