# How to get components from a JFrame with a GridLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, grid-layout

I have a question about Java and `JFrame` in particular. Let's say I have a `JFrame` that I am using with a `GridLayout`. Supposing that I have added `JButton`s in the `JFrame`, how can I gain access to the one I want using it's position (by position, I mean a x and a y, used to define the exact place on the Grid). I have tried several methods, for instance `getComponentAt(int x, int y)`, and have seen that those methods do not work as intended when combined with `GridLayout`, or at least don't work as intended in my case. So I tried using `getComponent()`, which seems fine.

The latest method, that seems to be on a right track for me is (assuming I have a `JFrame` with a `GridLayout` with 7 rows and 7 columns, x as columns, y as rows):

```
public JButton getButtonByXAndY(int x, int y) {
    return (JButton) this.getContentPane().getComponent((y-1) * 7 + x);
}
```

[image http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/9d6hq.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/9d6hq.jpg)

Using the above, say I want to get the `JButton` at (4, 4), meaning the 25th JButton in the `JFrame`, I would index through the first 21 buttons at first, and then add 4 more, finally accessing the JButton I want. Problem is this works like that in theory only. Any ideas?

P.S sorry for linking to an external website, but stack overflow won't allow me to upload the image, because I do not have the required reputation.

Comment: It's probably better to just hold on to a reference to the object in the first place. Can you show us where you're adding them?

Comment: I am adding them on a class that Extends a JFrame using the JFrame.add(JButton) method with a for loop.

Comment: Why not put them into an `ArrayList` first, then put add all the buttons in the list to the JFrame? Then you'll have a reference to each one you can use later on instead of trying to work out which one you want from their positions.

Comment: Will try this, and report on the results. Thank you for your input so far.

Comment: What if it is really necessary to do it with an x and y? I am using a class that extends the JButton class, and I am using a Point variable to store its position on the JFrame. Shouldn't I use the the method I posted on the question?

Comment: But you could just use the JButton's `getLocation` and `setLocation` methods... Anyway, that wouldn't stop you holding onto the reference to the object.

Comment: Your getLocation method just showed me how terribly bugged my code is right now. Even though I am initializing the JButtons in for loops and pass the x and y loop counter each time as the Point position of the Button, when I set it to print the brick's position, all of them report it's 0.0. Seems like I have a hella lot of work to do.

Comment: Hmmm... could you edit your post to contain a full, compilable example to show how you're doing these things?

Comment: Ah! I thought you were talking about pixel positions! Clearly you weren't. Sorry... (But you could still keep a list of the buttons you put into the layout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706684/230513) compares two approaches:

1. Maintain a `List<JButton>` and calculate the index algebraically.
2. Extend `JButton` and allow each button to maintain its own grid location.

Answer (score 1):

GridLayout start at 0,0 and JButton 
at (4,4 -position in GridLayout) meaning 
the 32th (4*7+4  not 3*7+4) JButton in the 
JFrame. Sorry if I misunderstood the questions :(

You can try:

```
   public static JButton getButtonByXAndY(int x, int y) {
        return (JButton) f.getContentPane().getComponent(y * 7 + x);
    }
```

Comment: How did you come up with the 32th? I hope you failed there, because in any other case, I have failed, miserably.

Comment: Does your frame like this ?                                       b0,0  b0,1 .... b0,6   /n b1,0 ....b1,6  /n  .... b6,0 ...b6,6    and then b4,4 meaning the 32th