# How to model which JButtons was pressed Tic Tac Toe Game

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I already written 4 classes for the game all in the Java language. There are for launching the game, game Logic, J Buttons and the game Board.
I created and added all 9 Buttons into a Grid Layout using a for loop. Each button has an actionListener.

How to model which J Button the user pressed. If I know that piece of information, I am sure I can use an array of characters to model the game logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get X and Y index of element inside GridLayout?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7702697/230513)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using separate `AbstractAction` listeners, it would look something like:

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[9];
for (int i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i] = new JButton("X or O here");
    buttons[i].addActionListener(new MyAction());
    add(buttons[i]);
}
```

Comment: ehhh .. you are on the right track, but stopping mid-ways: using an Action is _the_ thingy to do. But instead of adding it as mere actionListener, go full blast and do a _setAction_

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that is the question, you could use [setActionCommand](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setActionCommand%28java.lang.String%29) methods to assign an action to a button. And then retrieve it from `ActionEvent` with `getActionCommand()`. See [How to Use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details and examples.

You also can use `ActionEvent.getSource()` to get the object that originated the event, ie the button that was pressed.

Comment: I am testing the getSource method. I will think some more about this. Thanks Max and everyone!

Comment: eh .. no: use _Actions_, not actionListeners