# How should I identify buttons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I would *really* appreciate an answer:
I have a few JButtons generated with this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        buttons[ i] = new JButton(blank);
        if(i == 3 || i == 6){
            newLine++;
            lineCount = 0;
        }
        buttons[ i].setBounds(lineCount*150,newLine*150,150,150);
        cont.add(buttons[ i]);
        buttons[ i].addActionListener(this);
        lineCount++;
    }
```

so of course they don't have global names...
Because of this, I need to know how to take the image "***out***" of the JButton so I know what kind of button it is *or* be able to identify buttons by name(?).
So how can I do this? Thanks!
by the way, `cont` is a `java.awt.Container`

Comment: Best to get rid of the `null` layout and the `setBounds` calls. Use a `LayoutManager` instead

Comment: Rows in DB tables are identified by string IDs and not by images. There could be an analogy here :)

Comment: For a rectangular array of buttons, see this [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7706684/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `setIcon()` and `getIcon()` methods to set and get image-icons on JButton

### Edit in question, demands edit in answer:

Identification of button is best done with either:

1. `Component.getName()` and `Component.setName()` or
2. using different strings with `getText()` and `setText()`.

Comment: I have >60K and still feel like a newbie.  ;)

Comment: I have >3K and I feel like I haven't learnt a thing. I mean look at JonSkeet or something man, those people are legends

Comment: @AndrewThompson is the question ok now?

Comment: Yes, the question is better expressed now, and more open to inviting other strategies to achieve the goal.  :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't find a good approach to identify buttons based on their icons. Your components, including `JButton`s, can have names that you can use for identification. This is how acceptance testing tools work.

```
button.setName(uniqueName);
button.getName();
```

Comment: *"I don't find a good approach to identify buttons based on their icons."*  +1  I was typing much the same as a comment.  This question reeks of bad code design from even reading the title.

Comment: This question can be restated as how to retrieve an imageicon from the JButton

Comment: The question may be restated to sound fine, but the goal is really funny. Once you get the image icon, how do you identify the button? Do you make a pixel by pixel comparison?

Comment: You area aware of `Event.getSource()`?  Much easier way to identify which button was clicked, though most would recommend adding a separate listener to each button, wherein the source is clear.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I use an action listener but I don't know why I'm getting an EventDispatchThread error.

Answer (score 2):

use `putClientProperty` for identifying JComponent

```
buttons[i][j].putClientProperty("column", i);
buttons[i][j].putClientProperty("row", j);
buttons[i][j].addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
```

and get from ActionListener (for example)

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
        System.out.println("clicked column " + btn.getClientProperty("column")
                + ", row " + btn.getClientProperty("row"));
}
```

but proper way for `JButton` should be to use [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) instead of `ActionListener`

Comment: Also consider `putClientProperty()` with `java.awt.Point`.