# How to get the position of JButton?

Tags: java, swing, location, jbutton

I want to get the position of the `JButton` to have the return a value. I need the value to print out the element in an array list.   I have ten elements in the array list.  A `GridLayout(0,2)` was used to layout the buttons.

So what should I do?

```
                 for(int i=0;i<item.size();i++)
                {
                    JButton btn1= new JButton(item.get(i).print());

                    btn1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,40));

                    panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));

                    panel2.add(btn1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                    content.add(panel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                }
            public Food selectFood(int input)
            {

                int get=0;

                if(input>0 && input< 11)
                {
                     item.get(input-1);

                }
```

want to get the position as an input to print the selected item.

Comment: Are you looking for the button's [grid location](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7702697/230513) or it's pixel coordinates?

Comment: As a general tip.  If you need a reference to a GUI control, keep a reference rather than 'hunting' for the control later.

Answer (score 4):

I remember that it can use `JButton.getBounds()` function, then it can use `JButton.getBounds().x` and `JButton.getBounds().y` to get its upper-left corner position.

Comment: For just the position, then `JButton#getLocation()` is adequate, as it returns the x, y Point that represents the component's location in its container.

Comment: you should use getX and getY because it does not cause heap allocations.