# How do I tell which button is being clicked in an array of buttons?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get X and Y index of element inside GridLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702697/how-to-get-x-and-y-index-of-element-inside-gridlayout)

I have an 2D array of buttons that I wish to use. When I want to call an actionListener, how to I tell which button index in this 2D array of mine is being clicked? This is my first time dealing with a listener, so please explain this on a more basic level if you can.

Here is some code of how I have my buttons laid out on a gride (12x12)

```
//A loop to add a new button to each section of the board grid.
for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
    gameButtons[i][j] = new JButton();
    gameButtons[i][j].setBackground(colors[(int)(Math.random() * numColors)]);
    boardGrid.add(gameButtons[i][j]);

    try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }

  }
}
```

These buttons are randomly assigned a color from an array of colors created earlier. I now have to override actionlistener and I don't know how to do that in a way which allows me to get the button being pressed and compare it to other buttons around it. I would like to mention that I am dealing with static methods.

Comment: Could you post some sample code and show us how you implemented it?

Comment: See also [How to get X and Y index of element inside GridLayout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702697/how-to-get-x-and-y-index-of-element-inside-gridlayout)

Comment: Why on earth are you setting the look-and-feel at each iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should register all of your buttons with an actionlistener by this method `addActionListener()`. Then within the `actionPerformed()` method you should call `getSource()` to get a reference to the button which was clicked.

Check this [post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/376375/java/java/array-Jbutton-event-getSource)

Anyway here is the code, The gameButtons[][] array has to be available globally

```
//A loop to add a new button to each section of the board grid.
for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) 
{
  for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) 
  {
    gameButtons[i][j] = new JButton();
    gameButtons[i][j].addActionListener(this);
    gameButtons[i][j].setBackground(colors[(int)(Math.random() * numColors)]);
    boardGrid.add(gameButtons[i][j]);

    try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) { } 
  }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) 
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) 
     {
       if(ae.getSource()==gameButtons[i][j]) //gameButtons[i][j] was clicked
       {
             //Your code here
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I do apologize, I forgot to mention I am doing this inside a static class so using "this" won't work. Is there a way to do this even though I am in a static method without changing the method?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid looping over the arrays again, you can store the indices in the `JButton` as well.

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.putClientProperty( "firstIndex", new Integer( i ) );
button.putClientProperty( "secondIndex", new Integer( j ) );
```

and then in your `ActionListener`

```
JButton button = (JButton) actionEvent.getSource();
Integer firstIndex = button.getClientProperty( "firstIndex" );
Integer secondIndex = button.getClientProperty( "secondIndex" );
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution looks a lot more optimal than using two loops.

Answer (score 1):

if you need the **index** of the pressed button, try this:

```
private Point getPressedButton(ActionEvent evt){
    Object source = evt.getSource();
    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++){
            if(buttons[i][j] == source)
                return new Point(i,j);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then you can extract the value by

```
Point p = getPressedButton(evt);
```

And this means:

> > > Button pressed == buttons[p.x][p.y]

Otherwise, a simple call `evt.getSource();` does the job.