# actionListener on a JButton created from vector

Tags: java, swing, vector, jbutton, actionlistener

I've been searching the web for an answer to my specific basic problem, but was unable to find one. 
I must say I am new to programming and I have to do this for school.
I have created an interface of a 6/49 lottery, where you have to click 6 JButtons, creating your "lucky" numbers.  In my interface .java, I've created my buttons this way:

```
JButton b;
        for (i = 1; i <= 49; i ++)
        {           
            String  s = String.valueOf(i);
            b = new JButton(s); 
            if (i % 2 == 0)            
                b.setForeground(new Color(3, 121, 184));
            else
                b.setForeground(new Color(228, 44, 44));            

         choixNumero.add(b);
```

Note: "choixNumero" is a gridLayout ( 7 x 7 )

In another .java , I'm creating an actionListener to my JButton b, but that doesn't seems to work. Here is how I wrote it:

```
intProjet.b.addActionListener(new EcouteurCombinaison()); // where "intProjet" is my interface.java
```

and heres the code of my EcouteurCombinaison:

```
private int []  nums;
private int    nbRestant = 6;
private class EcouteurCombinaison implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (nbRestant > 0)
        {
            //nums[nbRestant] = indexOf(e)); //will have to find a way to get index of the button pressed
            nbRestant --;
            intProjet.valNbRestant.setText("" + nbRestant);
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vous avez choisis vos 6 numéros\n Cliquer sur Soumettre pour valider", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);   
        }    
    }
}
```

So basically, I'm trying to add the index or the value of my JButton to the vector everytime a button is pushed. I will then send it to another .java

I've implemented others actionListener to my code and they work fine ( JButton, RadioButton, JComboBox ). I don't understand why nothing happens when I click my buttons.

I tried to make this as clear as possible, without pasting all the code.

**Edit:** The ActionListener works with the **last** button only ( 49 ). How can I make it listen to all **b** Buttons ?

Comment: Maybe EcoteurCombinaison.actionPerformed throws an exception. Are there any error messages in the console? Also, what is that  `indexOf(e))` ?

Comment: I have no error when running it. The only "bad" part is : nums[nbRestant] = indexOf(e));  So i put // before and everything work well.   the indexOf(e)) was an attempt to get the index of the JButton pressed, to add the index to the vector nums[]

Comment: Yes, it's bad because it is not correct Java.

Comment: if we forget the indexOf(e)), if I insert a **JOPmessageDialog** in my **EcouteurCombinaison**, it doesn't appear. Looks like **JButton b** is not recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intProjet.b` refers to the *last* button created in your loop, so the result is expected. Instead, you can give each button its own instance of a listener, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706684/230513).

Comment: That makes sens. I am reading your code and trying to understand everything. Thank you for pointing why it was working with only the last JButton.

Comment: I understand the most of your method, but I don't have the knowledge to use it. My Listeners and my buttons are not in the same java file.  Could I refer the **JButton** to my other java file **Listener**, and that, every time it is generated ?  Sorry  if its vague. ( English is not my main language)

Comment: Yes, your buttons can use [_package-private_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) access to `EcouteurCombinaison`. Also consider [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Answer (score 2):

You are continually reassigning the value of `b` in that loop. When the loop completes, the last `JButton` to be created is assigned to it. You then bind an ActionListener to that button, but none of the others. I'm not sure why you expected a single invocation of `intProjet.b.addActionListener()` to add it to all JButtons.

Comment: I tough it would refer to all **b** elements. Beginner mistake. I will remember