# Creating a clickable JButton matrix

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

What i want to accomplish is:

*A window containing a matrix of buttons. Let's say 10x10.

*The buttons should say either "1" or "0", and change when I click them.

*The values of the buttons (1 or 0) should be stored in a `String[][]` matrix.

At the moment I have a `String[][]` 2D-array containing values. I can show it in a window with clickable buttons using the following code:

```
//dim = 10
//matrix is the 10x10 String[][] matrix containing 1s or 0s

private static void convertMatrixToGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Window containing a matrix");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(dim, dim));

    for(int r = 0; r < dim; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < dim; c++){
            p.add(new JButton(matrix[r][c]));
        }
    }
    f.add(p);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

The next step is to change the values in the matrix when clicking the buttons. If i click a 0 it should change it to a 1 and vice versa. The values have to be stored in the `String[][]` at all times.

How do i change things in the string matrix by clicking a button in the graphical matrix? If i click the button at position `[5][2]`, how should the program know that I want to change the string matrix as position `[5][2]`?

Best regards Goatcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give you an example of a `JButton` extension called `ChangingButton` that has matrix position and matrix assigned to it. Also, it creates an `ActionListener` that will change the name on the click.

```
public static class ChangingButton extends JButton {

    private final int[][] fModel;
    private final int fX;
    private final int fY;

    public ChangingButton(final int x, final int y, final int[][] model) {
        fX= x;
        fY= y;
        fModel= model;

        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fModel[fX][fY] = fModel[fX][fY] == 1 ? 0 : 1;
                updateNameFromModel();
            }
        });
        updateNameFromModel();
    }

    private void updateNameFromModel() {
        setText(String.valueOf(fModel[fX][fY]));
    }

}
```

This is your main test class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int dim=10;
    int matrix[][] = new int[10][10];

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Window containing a matrix");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(dim, dim));

    for(int r = 0; r < dim; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < dim; c++){
            ChangingButton button= new ChangingButton(r, c, matrix);
            p.add(button);
        }
    }
    f.add(p);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);

}
```

Hope it helps. If you don't understand something, please ask.

Answer (score 4):

[`GridButtonPanel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706684/230513) illustrates the basic principle. Substitute `JToggleButton` to get the effect of a binary selected/not-selected state.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

what you need is an ActionListener.

this Tutorial give you an idea how to use it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Answer (score 2):

Try it

```
        int DIM = 10;
    String [][]matrix = new String[DIM][DIM];
    JButton [][]butt = new JButton[DIM][DIM];

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Window containing a matrix");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();

    for(int r=0; r<DIM; r++){
        for(int c=0; c<DIM; c++){
            butt[r][c] = new JButton(matrix[r][c]);
            p.add(butt[r][c]);
            butt[r][c].addActionListener(this); //if your class extends ActionListener
        }
    }

    f.add(p);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
```

and override the actionPerformed method.
Implementing your code :)

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(int r = 0; r < dim; r++) {
       for(int c = 0; c < dim; c++){
           JButton temp = new JButton(matrix[r][c])
           temp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                matrix[r][c] = (matrix[r][c].equals("0")) ? "1" : "0"; //or for changing text of the button this.setText("1") or "0"
              }
           })
          p.add(temp);
       }
   }
```