# Java Grid with button + id to each button

Tags: java, swing, loops, button, grid

I'd like to make a grid in a JPanel full of buttons, then i want to create them in a loop because i've  aproximatly 100 buttons.
Each button created must have an id differents 
see my picture to understand better :s

I think I have to create a method like this but I don't know how to proceed :

```
public Button(String text , int id){
     //code 
}
```

And then add it to a loop to create the grid :)

[image]

if anyone can help me it would be very appreciated ! ;)

Comment: How do you think you might do it? You even put "loops" in the tags...

Comment: whatever your problem (is it the loop? is it the id? is it the layout? is it ...?): tackle it one by one, best with the help of your textbook (it's **your** homework, after all, nobody here will do it for it ;-)

Comment: my problem is the id and the layout , and sorry for tags @Tim B

Comment: I wasn't complaining about the tag. I was pointing out that the tag already contains half the answer you need. You are unlikely to get much help on this unless you come back with a much more specific question and show what you have tried.

Comment: @Clyx: Please feel free to update you question using the example cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21073559/230513)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get X and Y index of element inside GridLayout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702697/how-to-get-x-and-y-index-of-element-inside-gridlayout)

Answer (score 2):

Each [`GridButton`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706684/230513) "knows its location on the grid." The complete example shows how to create the buttons in a loop and how to calculate grid coordinates in a `List<GridButton>`.

[image]

Comment: _extending_ JButton just to place it somewhere? Boooohhh...

Comment: In this case, the intent is to demonstrate identity between inherent state and derived state.

Comment: not good enough a reason, IMO - especially not for newbies, it's simply a bad example of what not to do with JSomething ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra: On reflection, you're right; original updated.