# My way to get X and Y index of buttons inside GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, java-7, layout-manager

This is related to [How to get X and Y index of element inside GridLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702697/how-to-get-x-and-y-index-of-element-inside-gridlayout) post and its answers.

For whatever reason none of them suggested to extend `JButton` to include its position in the grid and in associated array of buttons.

I have made the following illustration that simply displays button's coordinates when it's clicked.

Extended `JButton`:

```
package buttons_array;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ButtonWithCoordinates extends JButton {

    int coordX;
    int coordY;

    public ButtonWithCoordinates(String buttonText, int coordX, int coordY) {
        super(buttonText);
        this.coordX = coordX;
        this.coordY = coordY;
    }

    /**
     * @return the coordX
     */
    public int getCoordX() {
        return coordX;
    }

    /**
     * @return the coordY
     */
    public int getCoordY() {
        return coordY;
    }
}
```

sample GUI:

```
package buttons_array;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonsArray implements ActionListener {

    private ButtonWithCoordinates buttons[][];
    private int nRows;
    private int nCols;

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;

    public ButtonsArray(int x, int y) {
        if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
            nRows = x;
            nCols = y;
            buttons = new ButtonWithCoordinates[nRows][nCols];
            for (int i=0; i < nRows; ++i) {
                for (int j=0; j < nCols; ++j) {
                    buttons[i][j] = new ButtonWithCoordinates("        ", i, j);
                    buttons[i][j].addActionListener(this);
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal array dimensions!!!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ButtonWithCoordinates button = (ButtonWithCoordinates) e.getSource();
        button.setText(button.getCoordX() + ", " + button.getCoordY());

    }

    public void GUI() {

        if (buttons == null) { throw new NullPointerException("Array is not initialized!!!"); }

        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(nRows, nCols));
        for (int i=0; i < nRows; ++i) {
            for (int j=0; j < nCols; ++j) {
                panel.add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ButtonsArray(3, 5).GUI();
            }
        });         

    }

}
```

Now my questions:

1. Have I been reinventing the wheel here?  I mean, is there a more straightforward way to achieve the same?
2. Is it in any way inferior to searching through the array each time we need to find the coordinates?

Comment: Will your buttons end up being the same width?

Comment: it's inappropriate subclassing: a) no new functionality that evolves its button-ness b) highly brittle - a class should be in full control of guaranteeing its contstraints and your comp can't because it's someone else who adds it to a grid c) there are several ways to easily reach the same without subclassing d) ...

Comment: @Teeg - Yes, as long as `GridLayout` is used.

Comment: @kleopatra - `b` - it allows to use either `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout`; `c` - care to give examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original [version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7706684/1) of this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706684/230513) used extension:

```
GridButton extends JButton
```

The updated [version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706684/230513) was predicated on the colloquy seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21073559/230513). While extension may be appropriate in some contexts, a few alternatives are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12424413/230513); a client property is particularly convenient. Identifying a button from its grid coordinates is also easy:

```
private static final int N = 5;
List<JButton> list = new ArrayList<>();
…
private JButton getGridButton(int r, int c) {
    int index = r * N + c;
    return list.get(index);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your very informative answer. So which approach would you personally consider the most appropriate when dealing with an array of some descendants of `JComponent`?  I also have one *unrelated* question to ask.  You used `EventQueue.invokeLater(...)` in your example. Tutorials that I've seen want us to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`. Is one any more suitable than the other?

Comment: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` "is just a cover for `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater()`." On design, see Bloch, [_op cit._](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4709813/230513), especially items 16 & 17