# Finding the source of an ActionEvent in a JButton[][] array without using nested loops?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, loops, jbutton

I've created a `JFrame` application with an 8x8 array of `JButtons[][]` corresponding to an array of selected & deselected `ImageIcon`s. When a button is pressed, it selects that button using `setSelection()` and deselects any other buttons. However, If any button adjacent to the selected button is pressed, the selected button and the adjacent button will swap `ImageIcons`.

I've successfully managed to do most of this, however using nested loops within an `ActionEvent` to determine adjacent buttons, the selected button, and deselected buttons simultaneously becomes a logical nightmare.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
    if (event.getSource() == buttons[row][col]) {
      if (row<7) buttonsAdjacent[row+1][col] = true;
      if (row>0) buttonsAdjacent[row-1][col] = true;
      if (col<7) buttonsAdjacent[row][col+1] = true;
      if (col>0) buttonsAdjacent[row][col-1] = true;
      buttons[row][col].setSelected(true);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I put `actionListeners` into each adjacent button at array index `[row][col]` to determine if an adjacent button has actually been pressed? And how can I reassign those `actionListeners` every time a new button has been selected?

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7702697/2305130)?

Comment: Absorutery like that, thanks dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706684/230513), you can calculate the index of a `JButton` in a `List<JButton>` as a function of the row and column for a given grid size, e.g. `N * N`. See the comments and [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7706684/revisions) for alternatives.

```
private static final int N = 5;

private JButton getGridButton(int r, int c) {
    int index = r * N + c;
    return list.get(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just add an actionlistener to every JButton in the 2D Array?

```
buttons[row][col].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//Your code that should execute on a click on the Object here
}
);
```

I guess these actionlisteners will always stay available.