# creating a subclass of JSpinner error

Tags: java, swing, date, jspinner

So I want to create a subclass of JSpinner so that I can hide all the configuration. The problem is when I put this object on JFrame, I get UI not found error.

I can't find out what I missed..

```
public class Time extends JSpinner {

    public Time() {
        super();
        SpinnerDateModel SpinnerModel = new SpinnerDateModel();
        this.setModel(SpinnerModel);

        JSpinner.DateEditor dateEditor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(this, "hh:mm a");
        this.setEditor(dateEditor);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you setting 'this' object in JFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked for me. Try it like this :

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] f) {
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        myFrame.add(new Time());
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Time extends JSpinner {

    public Time() {
        super();
        SpinnerDateModel SpinnerModel = new SpinnerDateModel();
        this.setModel(SpinnerModel);

        JSpinner.DateEditor dateEditor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(this, "hh:mm a");
        this.setEditor(dateEditor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to create a subclass of `JSpinner` so that I can hide all the configuration.

It's difficult to justify extending `JSpinner` in this context. As an alternative, consider using a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) to create and configure the spinner.

```
private JSpinner createSpinner() {
    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
    SpinnerDateModel SpinnerModel = new SpinnerDateModel();
    spinner.setModel(SpinnerModel);
    JSpinner.DateEditor dateEditor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "hh:mm a");
    spinner.setEditor(dateEditor);
    return spinner;
}
```

A related example is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706684/230513); see the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7706684/revisions) for details.