# Getting JPanel[][] coordinates by clicking on a JPanel

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jpanel, coordinates

I've created a `JPanel[][]` Array.

```
private JPanel[][] pnlFeld;
```

And filled it with panels

```
for (int i = 0; i < world.getSize(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < world.getSize(); j++) {
            pnlFeld[i][j] = new JPanel();
            pnlFeld[i][j].setBorder(new EtchedBorder());
            pnlFeld[i][j].addMouseListener(ml);
            pnlFeld[i][j].setBackground(off);
            add(pnlFeld[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to get the array coordinates (`[][]`) by clicking on them and I have no clue how to do that.

I've only added methods to change the color of the panel I clicked on, nothing related to my problem.

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            if (world.getMode().equals("Malen")) {
                if (e.getSource() instanceof JPanel)
                    e.getComponent().setBackground(on);
            //  check();
            } 
            else if (world.getMode().equals("Radieren")) {
                if (e.getSource() instanceof JPanel)
                    e.getComponent().setBackground(off);
            //  check();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                if (world.getMode().equals("Setzen")) {
                    if (e.getSource() instanceof JPanel) {
                        if (e.getComponent().getBackground() == off) {
                            e.getComponent().setBackground(on);
                        } else
                            e.getComponent().setBackground(off);
                    }
                //  check();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    };
```

Comment: post your implementation of `ml` in  `addMouseListener`

Comment: How do you wish to get the coordinates? What I mean to say is that does this panel containing these subpanels has some variable say `x` and `y` that are to be set when any suppanel is clicked?

Comment: When I click on a panel I want to create a new Point with its coordiantes.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7702697/230513).

Comment: do you have a variable say `point` that you would set with this new point you create out of the coordinates?

Comment: Get the source of MouseEvent and search the array for a match...

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use getBounds() to get component location and size. If you mean the array indexes there could be multiple solutions.

1. Define a Map and place all your panels in the Map with String value e.g. i+":"+j (or define simple pojo class with 2 fields i and j.
2. Create unique listener for each JPanel to keep the i and j.
3. Place the panels in a containr with GridBagLayout then you can use gridBagLayoutInstance.getConstraints(theClickedPanel) and check row column of the constraint

Answer (score 1):

> Getting `JPanel[][]` coordinates by clicking on a `JPanel`

Use a `JButton[][]` with `ActionListener` for easier coding and a better user experience.  The `ActionEvent` has a `getSource()` method that will identify the button that was activated.

This [chess GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21142687/418556) uses buttons for the 64 places on the chessboard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you create your `MouseListener` in your loop, you can use `i` en `j` within the code of your listener. The drawback is that you'll have a bit more instances of your listener.

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest that you set the name of each `JPanel` as `i` and `j` in the loop where you declare and initialise the panels. As illustrated

```
pnlFeld[i][j].setName(i + "" + j);
```

And in your `mouseClicked` event check if the event source is an instance of `JPanel` and parse the name to get the x and y coordinates like this:

```
Integer.parseInt(p.getName().subString(0,1))
Integer.parseInt(p.getName().subString(1));
```