# Adding ChartPanel to CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, cardlayout

I have a pretty basic GUI organized with a `GridBagLayout`. The most complex portion is the bottom where West is populated with ScrollPane and the right is a panel with a `CardLayout` that has multiple ChartPanels so I can switch between a few graphs.

My issue comes when I start the program.

[image]

The resizing issue goes away after I resize the frame in any direction. I have confirmed the chartpanel is the issue because not adding this to the `CardLayout` panel fixes it. I create a blank `ChartPanel` and populate it later after some action is taken but this is what I've done:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chipmunk: Variant Data Collection Tool");
        JPanel hotspotPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        ChartPanel subHotspotPanel = new ChartPanel(null);
        JPanel indelHotspotPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JTextPane resultPane = new JTextPane();
        JPanel main = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel header = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        header.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(875, 600));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation(dim.width/2-frame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-frame.getSize().height/2);
        resultPane.setOpaque(false);
        resultPane.setEditable(false);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        DocumentFilter filter = new UppercaseDocumentFilter();
        JTextField geneField = new JTextField(10);
        ((AbstractDocument) geneField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(filter);
        geneField.setMinimumSize(geneField.getPreferredSize());
        JTextField proEffField = new JTextField(10);
        proEffField.setMinimumSize(proEffField.getPreferredSize());
        String[] mutTypes = { "missense", "nonsense", "frameshift", "nonframeshift"};
        JComboBox<String> mutTypeComboBox = new JComboBox<String>(mutTypes);
        JButton saveResultsButton = new JButton("Save to TSV");
        JPanel glass = (JPanel) frame.getGlassPane();
        JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
        JButton cosmicButton = new JButton("To COSMIC");
        JButton dataButton = new JButton("Show Data");
        dataButton.setEnabled(false);
        JButton goButton = new JButton("GO");

        c.weightx = 1.0;c.gridx = 0;c.gridy = 0;c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;c.ipadx=5;c.ipady=5;
        main.add(new JLabel("Gene: "), c);
        c.gridx = 1;c.gridy = 0;c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        main.add(geneField, c);
        c.gridx = 0;c.gridy = 1;c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        main.add(new JLabel("Protein Effect: "), c);
        c.gridx = 1;c.gridy = 1;c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        main.add(proEffField, c);
        c.gridx =0;c.gridy = 2;c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        main.add(new JLabel("Mutation Type: "), c);
        c.gridx =1;c.gridy = 2;c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        main.add(mutTypeComboBox, c);
        c.gridx =0;c.gridy = 3;c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        main.add(saveResultsButton, c);
        c.gridx = 0;c.gridy = 3;c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        main.add(goButton, c);
        c.gridx = 1;c.gridy = 3;c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        main.add(clearButton,c);
        c.gridx = 0;c.gridy = 3;c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        main.add(dataButton,c);
        c.gridx = 1;c.gridy = 3;c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        main.add(cosmicButton,c);
        c.gridx = 0; c.gridy =4;c.gridwidth =1; c.weightx = 1.0;c.weighty = 1.0; c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(resultPane);
        main.add(scrollPane, c);
        c.gridx = 1; c.gridy =4;c.gridwidth = 1; c.weightx = 1.0;c.weighty = 1.0; c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        hotspotPanel.add(subHotspotPanel, "SUBPANEL");
        hotspotPanel.add(indelHotspotPanel, "INDELPANEL");
        hotspotPanel.add(new JPanel(), "BLANK");
        main.add(hotspotPanel, c);
        frame.add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(main, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: `The resizing issue goes away after I resize the frame in any direction.` - sounds like you are adding components to the frame AFTER the frame is already visible. The `setVisible(true)` statement should be invoked AFTER all components have been added to the frame. If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Confirmed that is not the issue, updated post with SSCCE

Comment: The code doesn't compile we don't have access to the ChartPanel class. Again the point of a `SSCCE` is to simplify the code do demonstrate the problem. We don't just want a core dump of your current code. Do you really need all the components to demonstrate the problem. Chances are as you remove irrelevant code you will find the problem. We also don't have the DocumentFilter. Again, how is that relevant to a layout problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513), it's clear that a `ChartPanel` works correctly in a `CardLayout`. The example below overrides `getPreferredSize()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513), to establish an initial size for the `ChartPanel`. The use of `GridLayout` on each card allows the chart to fill the panel as the enclosing frame is resized.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36392696/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36243395/230513
 */
public class CardPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final Random r = new Random();
    private static final JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    private final String name;

    public CardPanel(String name) {
        super(new GridLayout());
        this.name = name;
        DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
        pieDataset.setValue("One", r.nextInt(10) + 10);
        pieDataset.setValue("Two", r.nextInt(20) + 10);
        pieDataset.setValue("Three", r.nextInt(30) + 10);
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D(
            "3D Pie Chart", pieDataset, true, true, true);
        chart.setTitle(name);
        this.add(new ChartPanel(chart) {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(500, (int)(500 * 0.62));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                create();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void create() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
            CardPanel p = new CardPanel("Chart " + String.valueOf(i));
            cards.add(p, p.toString());
        }
        JPanel control = new JPanel();
        control.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("\u22b2Prev") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
                cl.previous(cards);
            }
        }));
        control.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Next\u22b3") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
                cl.next(cards);
            }
        }));
        f.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.add(control, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```