# How can i have the time on x axis and control the scaling value on a button click using jfreechart?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

Basically i want to show the historic data on a jfreechart graph, for that thing i need to have a time series on x -axis with scaling of 10 min or anything which should be controlled by a button click(Basically scaling gets doubled on every click if the scaling is 10 min on button click the scaling should be 20 min) and if i press the "back" button i have to show the older time periods(on x axis) with their corresponding data on the graph.

How could i achieve this using jfreechart in an efficient way?

Comment: You can page through datasets for homogeneous charts, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513), or page through view components for heterogenous charts, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36392696/230513).

Comment: @trashgod all the functionality i explained in my question was done when i took the integer values on x-axis. but i wanted to have real time on x-axis and control the tick units/scale like 10min or 15min or 30min etc.. based on user need at runtime.